# Determine if the following expressions result in a scalar or vector field. If undefined, please explain why.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$F(x,y,z)$ is a vector field in space and $f(x,y,z)$ is a scalar field in space.

1. $\nabla \times (\nabla(\nabla \cdot F))$
2. $\nabla \times (\nabla \cdot (\nabla f))$
3. $ \nabla (\nabla \cdot (\nabla \times F))$
4. $\nabla(\nabla \times (\nabla \cdot F))$
5. $\nabla \cdot (\nabla \times (\nabla f))$
6. $\nabla \cdot (\nabla (\nabla \times f))$

I'm trying to study for a multivariable final and I am having trouble understanding when and why these expressions become undefined.

Comment: For each operator, you should write down what it takes as input, and what it outputs. For example, div takes in a vector field and outputs a scalar.

Comment: I applied that strategy, but I'm just having trouble understanding when the expressions become undefined.  Like what about the 2nd, 4th, and 6th expressions make these expression undefined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, in expression 2:

- $f$ is a scalar field
- $\nabla f$ is its gradient: it is a vector field
- $\nabla \cdot \nabla f$ is the divergence of this vector field, it is a scalar field
- $\nabla \times (\nabla \cdot \nabla f)$ is the curl of this scalar field: this is undefined as the curl operator takes a vector field as input.

Comment: Ahh, so that's it! So you can take the gradient of a scalar field but you cannot take the curl of it?

Comment: Indeed. Carefully check the definitions of gradient, curl, divergence. It should help you manipulate them, and understand their geometrical/physical meaning.